# looking for best way to progressively increase my leg muscles without making my hurt cartilage more hurt?

Tags: muscle, legs, knee-pain, press

I have **chondromalacia patella** under which the **cartilage** has become a lot **thinner** than a normal person's.

I have no idea why that happens to a young man like me.

I have not had any external injuries. However, I still hope to exercise my legs.

Squat leg workout, I think, does not fit me at the moment, so I have tried **seated leg press.**

**Is that the right way to start ?**

Because my knee caps really are not feeling good and I can hear **"click, click"** all the way during the workout.  That is a little intimidating to me.

I wanna ask, in my current situation, **what might be the best way to progressively increase my leg muscles without hurting my poor cartilage?**

Comment: This is a question for a physical therapist.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that @rrirower is correct. This is something that you should be working on with a professional in a one on one type of situation.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider quitting seated leg presses and other machine-based movements.  These can bias your exertion toward quad-dominance, which may exacerbate imbalances in forces in your knees.

Instead, do low-bar back squats to *proper* depth (which is *not* maximum/"ass-to-grass" depth).  Squats will strengthen both your posterior chain (hamstrings, glutes) and your quads in a way that minimizes the net anterior-posterior stress on your knees (and their cartilage).

Consider these threads:

1. ["dem crunchy knees (chondromalacia patellae)"](https://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/starting-strength-staff-coaches-q-and-a/66788-dem-crunchy-knees-chondromalacia-patellae.html)
2. ["Squats and chondromalacia patella"](https://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/starting-strength-staff-coaches-q-and-a/38784-squats-chondromalacia-patella.html)